# Android Layout Design

Tags: android, shapes

I want to design the xml page In Circle Shape (Like Google Chrome Logo). It should contains the Buttons in outside circle as well in the inside cirlce. Please give me Suggestions to overcome this Problem. i have tried with Absolute Layout but i'm unable to do it .

[image: Sample image]

i need a layout like this.  Hoping for better response. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case, I would actually just use one image and then get the color of the pixel at the coordinates where the user clicked and act based on that. Other than that, maybe you can do something by tracing each "button" with a [`Path`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html). You'll have to build it up with [`lineTo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#lineTo%28float,%20float%29) and maybe [`arcTo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#arcTo%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float%29) and then use [`Region.setPath`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Region.html#setPath%28android.graphics.Path,%20android.graphics.Region%29) to get a `Region` and then test using [`Region.contains`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Region.html#contains%28int,%20int%29).

Answer (score -1):

You may give a try ...Make imagebuttons using .9png where you should try from designing point of you to give the shape like that ...becoz when you apply .9png's it stretches the button in that designing way .. I am not so sure but it's trial and error method ..you may give it a try

Comment: I struggle to understand how this answers the question. Can you explain your solution in more detail?